# Aligning datetime formats for comparrison

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having trouble align two different dates. I have an excel import which I turn into a `DateTime` in pandas and I would like to compare this `DateTime` with the current `DateTime`. The troubles are in the formatting of the imported DateTime.

Excel format of the date:

```
2020-07-06 16:06:00 (which is yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss)
```

When I add the DateTime to my `DataFrame` it creates the datatype Object. After I convert it with pd.to_datetime it creates the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.` It seems that the month and the day are getting mixed up.

Example code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('my path')
df['Arrival'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Arrival'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Expected result:
2020-06-07 16:06:00

Actual result:
2020-07-06 16:06:00

How do I resolve this?

Gr,

Sempah

Answer (score 0):

An ISO-8601 date/time is always yyyy-MM-dd, not yyyy-dd-MM. You've got the month and date positions switched around.

While localized date/time strings are inconsistent about the order of month and date, this particular format where the year comes first always starts with the biggest units (years) and decreases in unit size going right (month, date, hour, etc.)

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But somehow I can't make it work. Simple changing the format from format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S' to format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' doesn't work. The result in the DateFrame is still in the incorrect order.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. I think that I misunderstood the results. It already was working without me knowledge. Thanks for the help anyway.